# Strange behaviour for db2 query for timestamp data type

Tags: database, db2

I want to query for timestamp data type in db2.
I wrote query below

`Select * from sample where LASTMODIFIEDDATE = timestamp('2012-04-03 07:59:50')`

I didn't get any result for above query , then I tried

`Select * from sample where LASTMODIFIEDDATE > timestamp('2012-04-03 07:59:50')`

In above query I got results matching timestamp '2012-04-03 07:59:50' plus for greater values of timestamp, e.g '2012-04-03 08:59:50'.

If I am getting results for '>' operator then why not I am not getting any results for '=' operator ?
Any reasons or am I writing wrong query ?

Thanks !

Comment: A timestamp includes fractional seconds, are there any in your column?

Comment: No, there are no fractional seconds.

Comment: @Ben :: Apparently timestamp column shows value  '2012-04-03 07:59:50', 
Does db2 truncate fractional value and then store in database ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, DB2 stores the full value of the timestamp, including the fractional seconds.  You may wish to change the format the system displays timestamps in to something that includes milliseconds.

Try using this instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Sample
WHERE lastModifiedDate >= TIMESTAMP('2012-04-03 07:59:50')
AND lastModifiedDate < TIMESTAMP('2012-04-03 07:59:50)' + 1 SECONDS
```

Unless you have the *full* value of the timestamp, **including** milliseconds, you're going to be getting a range - when accessing a range of data, use 'lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive'.

Comment: Thanks @X-Zero 
I am getting results after trying query by you

Comment: :: One more question, what is upperbound for 24 hr clock , is it 23.59.59 ?

Comment: `23:59:59.999999`, yes (no milliseconds on `TIME`, but this is why you do upper-bound exclusive obviously).  As a note, this is the upper bound for this type on DB2 _only_ - other RDBMSs have similar/identical types that record to **different** resolutions, so you can't rely on what the 'exact' value will be.  So, always use the range like I've specified, and you'll _always_ (near as I know) be good.

Answer (score 0):

You could also truncate the db column's value to seconds alone and then perform the comparison with your string:

```
Select * from sample where TRUNC(LASTMODIFIEDDATE, 'SS') = '2012-04-03 07:59:50'
```

Works in DB2 10.5. You could also truncate by:

```
hour ('HH'), minute('MI'), year('YEAR' or 'YYYY'), month('MONTH' or 'MM'), Day ('DD')
```

Example:

```
Select * from sample where TRUNC(LASTMODIFIEDDATE, 'HH') = '2012-04-03 07:00:00'
Select * from sample where TRUNC(LASTMODIFIEDDATE, 'MI') = '2012-04-03 07:59:00'
```